# Using the paper_trail gem when a model has a UUID as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

The model I want to track with paper_trail has a UUID as primary key. On save, the `item_id` in the version record is `0`. So I changed the `item_id`'s column type to `uuid` (I'm using Postgres) but now I'm getting the following error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "0"
```

Is it even possible to use uuid's primary key for models tracked by paper_trail?

Comment: Can you give use the schema for your model table and the versions table? A stack trace would also be really useful.

Comment: @max Looking at the source code, I don't think it's possible to use UUIDs as a primary key. The model I'm using is very simple. It basically has a `uuid` as primary key, a `string` for the name and a `jsonb` column with data. Nothing special and it's a fresh Rails 6 app. If I use a string value for `item_id` in the migration for the `versions` table, I can see the value is converted to an intager somewhere.

Comment: Does your entire database use UUID primary keys, or are there some tables with e.g. integers? The later is more difficult, but [perhaps still possible](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/547#issuecomment-150681178).